# What is `data` in `firebase.init ({ onAuthStateChanged: function(data) ...`?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, nativescript

I am looking at this block of code:

```
firebase.init({
  onAuthStateChanged: function(data) { // optional but useful to immediately re-logon the user when he re-visits your app
    console.log(data.loggedIn ? "Logged in to firebase" : "Logged out from firebase");
    if (data.loggedIn) {
      console.log("user's email address: " + (data.user.email ? data.user.email : "N/A"));
    }
  }
});
```

It's from the [nativescript-firebase plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/AUTHENTICATION.md) authentication readme. I suspect it's the firebase instance, but can't be sure. I looked at the `firebase.android.js` file that contains the `onAuthStateChanged` listener, which leads me to believe that's what it is.

Comment: Given that the plugin is open-source, I recommend that you check the source. But an educated guess is that it's the same as this [`onAuthStateChanged` callback from the Firebase API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener.html#onAuthStateChanged(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth)).

Answer (score 1):

data is a Json,  that means, to had any information, in this case had ifnrmation of user, , if you see this "onAuthStateChanged"  that means  a variable been created and that will be use, how parameter from a method

Information of user

```
 data.user.email
```

get a boolean value

```
if (data.loggedIn) {
       ....
      }
```

New Variable  **listener**

```
var listener= {
        onAuthStateChanged: function(data) {
      ......
        }
      };
```

**listener** will be used how parameter

```
 // add the listener:
  firebase.addAuthStateListener(listener);

  // stop listening to auth state changes:
  firebase.removeAuthStateListener(listener);

  // check if already listening to auth state changes
  firebase.hasAuthStateListener(listener);
```